# Convert elements of an array to their base class type

Tags: arrays, swift, class, mapping, base-class

I am trying to convert the elements inside my array to their base class type:

```
extension Array{

    mutating func convertToBase<A>(type: A.Type){

        let parentArray = self.map{ $0 as type }
    }
}

class A {}
class B: A {}

let instanceB = B()
var array = [instanceB]
array.convertToBase(type: A.self)
```

but it keeps telling me this error:

> 'Use of undeclared type 'type''

[image]

Comment: What's the main purpose of doing this? I think it's a little weird to do such a functionality...

Comment: I know its kinda weird, but I need it in one of app cases :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make sense at all. If you have an array of `B` whose base class is of type `A`, why do you have to convert? Aren't all `B`s, also `A`s in the runtime?

"Converting" this should be as simple as:

```
let instanceB = B()
var array = [instanceB]
var aArray  = array as [A]
```

If you are hellbent on using YOUR method, this should do the trick:

```
extension Array{
    mutating func convert<G>(to type : G.Type) -> [G] {
        let parentArray = self.map {
            $0 as! G
        }
        return parentArray
    }
}
```

Note that this tries to convert ANY type to the generic type `G`. For example, this:

```
var anotherArray = array.convert(to: A.self)
```

... will trap if `B` is not a subtype of `A`. If it is a subtype of `A` `anotherArray` will also be `[A]`.  I can't believe I just wrote this practically useless function.